# Login form with repeat request on rxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, kotlin

I want to make login form on rxJava and retrofit. But if I got error while requesting server, unsubscribe is called from bottom of rx

I have ui methods which implemented by rxAndroidBinding lib

```
fun validEmail(): Observable<CharSequence> //last well formated login
fun validPassword(): Observable<CharSequence> //last password of length 
fun clicks(): Observable<Unit> //clicks on login buttons
```

I have register method which implemented by Retrofit

`fun authorize(email:String, pass:String): Observable<Unit>`

I want to make request if both input is valid and I have click of login button

```

```
    val validPair = rx.Observable.combineLatest(iView.validEmail(), iView.validPassword(), ::ValidLoginPair)
            .doOnNext { iView.setLoginButtonEnabled(true) }

    subscription = rx.Observable.combineLatest(validPair, iView.clicks(), { pair, unit -> pair })
            .doOnNext { iView.setProgress(true) }
            .flatMap {
                model.get().authorize(it.email.toString(), it.password.toString())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .doOnError {
                            it.printStackTrace();
                            iView.setProgress(false);
                            iView.showError("NetWorkError", it.message ?: "Unknown error")
                        }
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                iView.setProgress(false);
                iView.onLogin()
            }) {it.printStackTrace();  iView.setProgress(false);}
```

```

If I got 200 response, it works. But if onError  is called, all ui events subscriptions will be unsubscripted. So on second clicks nothing will happen.
What I do wrong? Why retrofit works that way?

---

versions

    `compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'`

unsubscripted stack

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
  at com.jakewharton.rxbinding.widget.TextViewAfterTextChangeEventOnSubscribe$2.onUnsubscribe(TextViewAfterTextChangeEventOnSubscribe.java:40)
  at rx.android.MainThreadSubscription.unsubscribe(MainThreadSubscription.java:72)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
  at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
  at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
  at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
  at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeCombineLatest$LatestCoordinator.cancel(OnSubscribeCombineLatest.java:178)
  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeCombineLatest$LatestCoordinator.unsubscribe(OnSubscribeCombineLatest.java:165)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
  at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeCombineLatest$LatestCoordinator.cancel(OnSubscribeCombineLatest.java:178)
  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeCombineLatest$LatestCoordinator.unsubscribe(OnSubscribeCombineLatest.java:165)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
  at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
  at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
  at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:814)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:573)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:562)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:846)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:72)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:276)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:219)
  at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:107)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ReactiveX [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html):

> An Observable may make zero or more OnNext notifications, each
>   representing a single emitted item, and it may then follow those
>   emission notifications by either an OnCompleted or an OnError
>   notification, but not both. Upon issuing an OnCompleted or OnError
>   notification, it may not thereafter issue any further notifications.

Retrofit calls `onError` if there is a network error or API error (code outside the range 200-300). After a call to `onError` the Observable is terminated.

Sorry for using Java in my example but one solution would be:

```
authorize(username, password).flatMap(() -> Observable.just(true))
    .onErrorReturn(e-> Observable.just(false))
```

This will make sure the `Observable` isn't terminated in case of an error. Instead it will emit false. For success it will emit true. You can replace the boolean with another class containing more data (maybe an error message).

Note: `onErrorReturn` will consume the error. `doOnError` does not consume the error, `onError` will still be called.

Comment: You need to use `onErrorReturn` inside `flatMap`, otherwise it doesn't change anything - sequence will just complete after first error (even though it was handled).